# Add author section on Author archive posts

Tags: posts, archives, author

I was looking at the section where you click on the author name on the homepage posts.

and it says the Archive posts from xxxx authors

so I thought of that while ago I found that some website has it and they including the twitter of that author and their bio with the pic

this is one of the example I would say

http://www.redmondpie.com/author/oliver.haslam/

I'm trying to look for this kind of plugin or maybe I can edit this to have it myself

but needed to ask if this been done from some plugin because I couldn't find one

all I see is the widget on the sidebar

Thanks

---

For more information I have looked from the plugin page and the tags from wordpress official site about author plugin.... none of them are similar to what I want on the above example link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/author

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-info-widget/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-bio/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-exposed/

Or you can use your own custom solution

Comment: Well it seem that none of it from where you post related to which I show on the first post

because all of the above you provided can be found on the plugin.php page but none of them are same like the one I want

it seem that I have to look a way to get something similar like that

or any suggestion....?

Comment: I'd probably search the wordpress.org site for plugins to suit your needs under the Author tag. If none are found you might want to create a custom Author page. [http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)
You may want to take a closer look at the external links posted on that page, something like this one [http://wpsplash.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-authors-page/](http://wpsplash.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-authors-page/)

Comment: Daniel, this answer popped up during my review. Please don't post answers that only rely on external links. When the links are gone, the answer is worthless and the site suffers from link rot. At least add the minimum lines of code that solve this question. Thanks.